# How to reference another project in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a repository with a typescript project that is generated by a generator (using OpenAPI). I do not want to touch these files

But I want to write some integration tests for that. So my project folder structure looks like this:

```
dist/
   index.js
   index.d.ts
src/
   index.js
tests/
   build/
     spec/
       index.spec.js
   helpers
   specs
     index.spec.ts
   tsconfig.json
   package.json
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

Everything except the `tests` folder is generated. Now I have to create a reference from /tests/package.json to /package.json.

I tried a few things and only none seems to work:

1. Just import files from the dist-folder directly: It compiles but then the relative paths do not match anymore, because the javascript files in one level deeper in the build folder.
2. Use a typescript reference. It basically creates the same problem as above.

How can I create a reference between my projects?